# Wrong sending and receiving photos through socket

Tags: java, android

This is code of client (android application):

```
Socket mSocket = new Socket();
mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("123.456.789.0", 50), 10000);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()));
OutputStream out = mSocket.getOutputStream();
out.write("image number 3".getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.flush();
FileInputStream mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFile); // mFile - photo
while (true) {
    byte[] i3 = new byte[65536];
    int i4 = mFileInputStream.read(i3, 0, 65536);
    if (i4 < 0) {
        mFileInputStream.close();
        break;
    } else {
        out.write(i3, 0, i4);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

And this code is server:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.in, "UTF-8"));
String i1 = in.readLine();
ByteArrayOutputStream i3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while (true) {
    try {
        byte[] i4 = new byte[1024];
        int i5 = this.in.read(i4, 0, 1024);
        if (i5 < 0) {
            throw new Exception();
        } else {
            i3.write(i4, 0, i5);
            i3.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        i3.close();
        break;
    }
}
BufferedImage mBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(i3.toByteArray()));
```

Practically 1/4 times when I trying to send photo on server and then read it with `ImageIO` I getting Exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at com.lnproduction.ru.gks.server.I1$WebClient.run(I1.java:101)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Line 101: `BufferedImage mBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(i3.toByteArray()));`. I also used debugger and it revealed: practically 1/4 times it sends 116K bytes, but received 113K! I really don't understand it is possible. Maybe I have some errors in my code? Help me solve it please. No ideas sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix buffered and unbuffered streams on the same socket. You're losing part of the image in the buffered reader. Try using nothing but `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputSream`, and send the filename via `writeUTF()/readUTF()`.

Comment: Thank you! I try it in 11 hours.

Comment: but i would like to use `write("...\n".getBytes("UTF-8"))` / `readLine()`.